# What is the reason behind this Error while using am4chart Lib?

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts, index-error

[ERROR !] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SO1pW.png

This is the error msg that happened sometimes while calling component to plot chart !!
Trying to remove it, Any help would be greatly appreciated !

```
await getScriptPromisify("https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js");
await getScriptPromisify("https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js");
await getScriptPromisify("https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js");
```

Comment: You are using indexOf, so make sure the values will not be undefined or null, You can solve it by putting the check on each values like this:

Comment: Thanks for the response !!
but here I'm not using indexOf in JS file of web component so I'm unable to debug and this error coming from this amcharts Lib that I've been using.